# cant remote add to github

Tags: github

This is the first commit I'm adding to git. I ave initialized git inside my directory and am trying to remote add following this command:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:pvenkat/Scribble-pad.git
```

But I receive a fatal error telling me remote origin already exists:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists
```

Does this mean I must remove the previous remote origin? If so how do i do that? If anyone knows whats wrong please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably already have the origin defined.

You can run,

`git remote rm origin`

Then,

`git remote add origin git@github.com:pvenkat/Scribble-pad.git`

Answer (score 1):

You can update the URL of your existing remote with the following command:

git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:pvenkat/Scribble-pad.git